# Lenovo ideapad 720 - ubuntu 18.04 does not recognize fingerprint-reader

Tags: 18.04, lenovo, fingerprint-reader

I installed a fresh 18.04 on my new laptop and it does not recognize the fingerprint-reader..
I tried to install fingerprint-gui as well as fprint, they both are not able to recognize the reader..

Below is the result of running the command: `lsusb`

```
Bus 002 Device 014: ID 05e3:0616 Genesys Logic, Inc. hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b5d9 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd 
Bus 001 Device 031: ID 24ae:2010  
Bus 001 Device 030: ID 1ea7:0064  
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. 4-port hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Let me know if you need more information please.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Bus 001 Device 004: ID 06cb:0081 Synaptics, Inc.

That is the fingerprint reader and Linux lack of driver to support it.

check this 
https://github.com/nmikhailov/Validity90